# How do I configure the amdloader in grunt-ts?

Tags: gruntjs, typescript

Using grunt-ts on my project, here is my Gruntfile:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
  grunt.initConfig({
    pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
    ts: {
      build: {
        src: ['ts-src/**/*.ts'],
        //compile using the requirejs module style
        module: 'amd',
        //write generated files to ts-out directory
        outDir: '../js/ts-out',
        amdloader: 'loader.js',
        //generate a reference file
        reference: 'reference.ts',
        //generate .d.ts files
        declaration: true,
        options: {
          comments: true, //preserves comments
          target: 'es5' //emit ECMAScript5 JS
        }
      }
    },
    watch: {
      files: ['<%= ts.build.src %>'],
      tasks: ['ts']
    }
  });

  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-ts');
  grunt.registerTask('default', ['watch']);
}
```

This "works", but it is generating a loader.js file that incorrectly prepends the `outDir` value onto the entries in the file. This results in a path for each file that contains js/ts-out, twice.

Does the `amdloader` option have configuration options, where I can override this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect it should be :

```
    outDir: '../js/ts-out',
    amdloader: '../js/ts-out/loader.js',
```

See : https://github.com/grunt-ts/grunt-ts/blob/master/Gruntfile.js#L101-L117 i.e.:

```
       amdloadersrc: {
            test: true,
            src: ['test/amdloader/ts/app/**/*.ts'],
            html: ['test/amdloader/ts/app/**/*.html'],
            reference: 'test/amdloader/ts/app/reference.ts',
            outDir: 'test/amdloader/js/app',
            amdloader: 'test/amdloader/js/app/loader.js',
            //  watch: 'test/amdloader/app'
        },
        amdloadertest: {
            test: true,
            src: ['test/amdloader/ts/test/**/*.ts'],
            html: ['test/amdloader/ts/test/**/*.html'],
            reference: 'test/amdloader/ts/test/reference.ts',
            outDir: 'test/amdloader/js/test',
            amdloader: 'test/amdloader/js/test/loader.js',
        },
```

amdloader takes an absolute path to the generated JS location

Comment: Thanks. That takes care of providing the correct paths to the referenced files in loader.js. I do wish I could have loader.js in a different location. But, I can fix that with some more grunt tasks...